# Use Mysql lower_case_table_names to 1

Tags: mysql, tablename

I have installed mysql v5.5.17 in linux using yum, now i want default lowercase table names so i have added

```
set-variable = lower_case_table_names=1
```

in 
`/etc/my.cnf`

but if i do that then i could not start mysqld service. Mysql logs says unknown variable `lower_case_table_names`.
I have also tried with `set global lower_case_table_names=1;` in command line but is says its read only variable.

any suggestion?

Comment: via @Dori - http://linux-tips.org/article/41/lowercase-table-names-in-mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 5.5 we need to specify

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Answer (score 21):

my OP system is ubuntu,
Mysql version is **5.5.***

update file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, (must add under the section `[mysqld]`)

```
[mysqld]

lower_case_table_names=1
```

then restart mysql

Comment: Under 16.04, this can be put at the end of `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Stop the mysql service using sudo systemctl stop mysqld;
Step2: Backup mysql folder from /var/lib
Step3: Delete /var/lib/mysql folder
Step4: Change lower_case_table_names=1 in /etc/my.cnf
Step5: Start the mysqld.service again using sudo systemctl start mysqld

If the root password is not working from mysql -u root -p, follow the below steps:

Edit the /etc/my.cnf file
Under [mysqld] add skip-grant-tables
Restart your MySQL server
You should be able to login to mysql now using the below command mysql -u root -p
Run flush privileges; inside the MySQL shell
Set new password with ALTER USER ‘root’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘your_new_password’;
Edit /etc/my.cnf and remove the skip-grant-tables line
Restart MySQL again
Now you can login with your new MySQL password using mysql -u root -p