# Linux set mysql case insensitive via query

Tags: mysql, linux

For linux server, i wants to set mysql case insensitive, this is possible via updating configuration file "my.cnf" and restarting mysql service.
But the issue is i neither wants update this file (my.cnf) not wants to restart mysql service, as the user may not have access to that file.

Is there a way to set case insensitive via query or any other way?

Thanks

Satish Lakhani

Comment: What query or queries do you have in mind where case sensitivity is an issue?

Comment: **lower_case_table_names** variable is read only. So the only way you can set it by writing through the my.cnf file. It's not possible to change the variable dynamically since it is read only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Mysql lower\_case\_table\_names to 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147447/use-mysql-lower-case-table-names-to-1)